# string sort in c++ nor sorted properly at 5th element

Tags: c++, string, sorting

please find below program, the sort output is not proper.

```
string pru[] = { "ruthvi$p", "uthvi$pr", "thvi$pru", "hvi$prut",    "vi$pruth", "i$pruthv", "$pruthvi", "pruthvi$" };

sort(pru, pru + 8, cmp);
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    cout << pru[i] << " ";
```

output is

```
$pruthvi hvi$prut i$pruthv pruthvi$ thvi$pru ruthvi$p uthvi$pr vi$pruth
```

mistake "`thvi$pru`" is before "`ruthvi$p`"

Comment: Show implementation of `cmp` and we'll talk I guess.

Comment: The error is not in the code you've shown us. It must be in code you haven't shown us. Presumably you've done `using ::std;` somewhere and so all your unqualified references to things that could be from the C++ standard library are actually referring to the C++ standard library. Given that, the error must be in your `cmp` function. Realize 10s of thousands of people use the C++ standard library on any given platform in any given day. You're not doing anything odd or unusual. So it's highly unlikely you've found a problem there.

Comment: Thanks I figured the problem in my cmp() function.
Yup I dont mean to say, there is problem in sort() impl of libc, it should be my invoking or implementation which should be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear how `cmp` is defined but you can use this code and you will get the expected result.:)

```
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::string pru[] = 
{ 
    "ruthvi$p", 
    "uthvi$pr", 
    "thvi$pru", 
    "hvi$prut",    
    "vi$pruth", 
    "i$pruthv", 
    "$pruthvi", 
    "pruthvi$" 
};

std::sort(std::begin(pru), std::end(pru));

for (const auto &s : pru) std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

The output is

```
$pruthvi
hvi$prut
i$pruthv
pruthvi$
ruthvi$p
thvi$pru
uthvi$pr
vi$pruth
```

Comment: my cmp() function is as below

    bool cmp(string a, string b)
    {
    if(a.compare(b) > 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
   }